# Java thread crashes silently - I can't catch the exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, executorservice, executors

I see a behavior from I can't explain

I have a Runnable that it's code is something of:

```
run()
{
    print("start");
    try{
        doSomething();
        print("end");    

    }catch (Exception e){
        print("problem");
    }
    print("method end");

}
```

The behavior is strange because the **only** print I get is "start" - I would expect to get the "problem" and the "method end" prints also. And if the doSomething handles the exception itself - so the "end" would be printed.
But I don't get any of the prints except "start"

Now i know that there is some issue with the doSomething method as if I run it not through the executor service, I get "Method Not Found" exception.

I think it might be somehow connected to the Executor service that I use - Executors.newFixedThreadPool, but I can't explain it

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`NoSuchMethodError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) is not derived from `Exception`:

```
java.lang.Object
    java.lang.Throwable
        java.lang.Error
            java.lang.LinkageError
                java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
```

so will not be caught by the posted `catch` clause. Change to catch `Throwable` or add a separate `catch` clause for `Error` and handle differently (attempt to recover from an `Exception` but report an `Error` and do not attempt to recover for example).

Answer (score 4):

Certainly an `Error` is thrown. Try catching `Throwable` instead.

Edit: Indeed, `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is an `Error`.